# Do static local variables in a class persist between objects?

Tags: c++, static, instance

```
class MyClass
{
  static int staticInt;

  void instanceMethod( int param )
  {
    static int parameter = param;
  }
}
```

Clearly `staticInt` is shared between all instance of MyClass.  But can different instances of MyClass have different values of `parameter` the static local variable within instaceMethod?

**Update**

What about between program executions?  Certainly they could be different in multiple program instances?  What defines "scope" there - the execution unit?  The c++ runtime?

**Update**

Thanks - this helped me squash a critical bug.  Wish I could accept them all, but I'm going with the first answer with no other criteria.

Comment: Just a note: initialization of `parameter` is usually not threadsafe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is exactly one instance of `parameter`.

If you want an instance of `parameter` for each instance of the class, use a nonstatic member variable.

Answer (score 8):

In order to have different values of `parameter` for different instances you have to make `parameter` a non-static member of the class.

In your current version all instances will share the same `parameter` object. All `static` objects behave exactly the same in that respect. The only thing that depends on the point of declaration is the *scope* of the name. i.e. the regions where the name is visible. As for the lifetime and the value-retaining properties of the variable - they are always the same. It that respect it is just like a "global" variable, regardless of where you declare it.

In your example, there's no difference between `parameter` and `staticInt` when it comes to their value-retaining properties. The only difference is that `staticInt` is accessible to all members of the class, while `parameter` is only accessible to `instanceMethod` method.

The language provides you with no means to create variables whose values persist between program executions. This kind of persistence has to be implemented manually.

Comment: @AudreyT - your first paragraph mentions making parameter a non-static member of the class.  Is it common to refer to static local variables in instance methods as static member?  Is this technically correct or rather since the effect is the same, we can consider it a static member?

Comment: @user144182: No, local static variables are not members of the class. In C++ "being a member" is a concept mostly related in scoping and naming, not to physical behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they both persist. They cannot have different values between instances.

Comment: What about between program execution?

Comment: No, they do not persist between executions.

Answer (score 0):

the values are not persistent across program execution(between two different invocation of the same program )